# mark git commit as not transferable

Tags: git, version-control, git-flow

We have a feature branch F that syncs with develop branch D (daily merge D --> F , monthly merge F --> D).

I now have a case were I want to create source code change that should not be synced to D but I still want to sync easily F --> D. Can Git somehow mark a commit as not transferable?

By this mark, I mean Git should filter this commit with merge all changes from branch F to branch D.

Answer (score 2):

You could try creating merge history for a commit without bringing the change over.

Branch off somewhere reachable by both D and F

```
git checkout -b not-transferable $(git merge-base F D)
```

Create your changes and commit

```
git checkout D
```

Create merge history on D without bringing the changes forward

```
git merge --strategy=ours not-transferable
```

Actually merge the file to F

```
git checkout F
git merge not-transferable
```

When you merge F to D it should (theoretically) not bring the changes for that one commit forward to D, while still bringing everything else.

Comment: That will work. Note that the checkout can be done from F head: `git checkout -b not-transferable F`; that sounds easier in the development process and even required if the changes apply to the new features.